# JavaScript error on FireFox ns_error_dom_security_err

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am getting the following error in FireFox only:

> Error: [Exception... "Security error"  code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 `(NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)`"  location: ""]

I know it has to do with calling CSS from another domain but I can't find any references to any domains!

How do I debug this?

Thanks!

Greg Wilson
PS: If this is a duplicate, I apologize.  I thought I posted this yesterday but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Firefox when I had a jQuery include line like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

But then I included a script that used jQuery like this:

```
<script type="javascript" src="/javascript/dialog_functions.js"></script>
```

When I changed the "type" attribute of the second line to "text/javascript" to match the jQuery include, the error went away. It appears to be some sort of security feature where the script types must match before they can reference each other.  Just guessing, though.  I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look at about:config and search for dom.storage.enabled being
sure that is set to true.